# Outlook shows that it's disconnected

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My Outlook shows that it's disconnected.

I checked the LAN cable, *Tools > Account Settings > E-mail & Data files*. I also restarted the system and Outlook.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Kabilan. Please keep your posts to the minimum necessary, not including greetings and salutations. Also, please at least mention your Windows version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing stale credentials from Control Panel / User Accounts and Family Safety / Credential Manager:

https://helpdesk.stanly.edu/support/solutions/articles/5000568822-clearing-outlook-credentials-resolve-disconnected-issues-

After many frustrating weeks since I upgraded to Outlook 365 (on Windows 8.1), being constantly disconnected and completely unable to either send or receive e-mail from my `@live.com` account, this has finally solved the problem for me.

`<RANT>` Microsoft should really get their act together, as this problem has been out for a couple of YEARS now (judging by old forum threads), preventing people from using the most essential function of Outlook: e-mail! `</RANT>`